# Operational error, no such table error in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have three database tables in my project. When I apply migrations, they are applied successfully and are visible on the admin site too. But when I click on one of the three database tables on the admin site, I get an operational error saying that table does not exist. The rest of the two tables work correctly.
I tried deleting the migrations folder and applying the migrations again. But the same error repeats.
The error is as follows

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/users/subscription/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users_subscription

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\hand
lers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\hand
lers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\hand
lers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\options.py", line 574, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\dec
orators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\views\dec
orators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\dec
orators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\dec
orators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\dec
orators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\options.py", line 1570, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\options.py", line 705, in get_changelist_instance
    self,
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\views\main.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\a
dmin\views\main.py", line 175, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\fun
ctional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\pagi
nator.py", line 85, in count
    return self.object_list.count()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models
\query.py", line 387, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models
\sql\query.py", line 491, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models
\sql\query.py", line 476, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models
\sql\compiler.py", line 1066, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\utils.
py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_subscription
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser, Profile, Subscription

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username','password1','password2']

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Profile)
admin.site.register(Subscription)
```

The error occurs when I click the Subscription table on admin site. 'users' is my app name.

When I apply migrations, the following is displayed. From this I think I can make sure that the table Subscription is created.

```
-- Create model Subscription
--
CREATE TABLE "users_subscription" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "fullname" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "ma
ilid" varchar(254) NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_customuser_groups_customuser_id_group_id_76b619e3_uniq ON "users_customuser_groups" ("customus
er_id", "group_id");
CREATE INDEX "users_customuser_groups_customuser_id_958147bf" ON "users_customuser_groups" ("customuser_id");
CREATE INDEX "users_customuser_groups_group_id_01390b14" ON "users_customuser_groups" ("group_id");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_customuser_user_permissions_customuser_id_permission_id_7a7debf6_uniq ON "users_customuser_use
r_permissions" ("customuser_id", "permission_id");
CREATE INDEX "users_customuser_user_permissions_customuser_id_5771478b" ON "users_customuser_user_permissions" ("customu
ser_id");
CREATE INDEX "users_customuser_user_permissions_permission_id_baaa2f74" ON "users_customuser_user_permissions" ("permiss
ion_id");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Did you customize the 'admin.py'?

Comment: @MiladHatami used admin.site.register(database) to register all the three databases.

Comment: Do you mean this? `admin.site.register(your model name)`

Comment: @MiladHatami Yes. I edited the question with admin.py. Please check it.

Comment: Are you sure the 'Subscription' table was created in the database?

Comment: Is your database contains important data?

Comment: @MiladHatami Yes. It is visible on the admin site too as I said.

Comment: @a_k_v No. It's in testing stage.

Comment: The 'admin site' uses the models to display. Not from the database.

Comment: @MiladHatami When I apply migrations, I'm sure the database table is created. I can even find it in the '0001_initial.py' in migrations folder. Please see the edited question for further reference.

Comment: If there is no important data then you can delete all migration file and databases then run makemigrations and migrate.